# Не получается выполнить ajax запрос путём сабмита в форме html

Tags: javascript, ajax

Доброго времени суток коллеги! В js я не силен и возможно это довольно глупый вопрос, но ответа нормального не нашел, надеюсь получить его здесь

Есть простой ajax запрос в функции getFinds():

```
var getFinds = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:  '/product/finds/iphone',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            var len = data.length;
            var txt = "";
            for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                var dataid = data[i].id;
                txt += "<tr>"+
                        "<td>"+data[i].id+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+data[i].name+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+data[i].brand+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+data[i].price+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+data[i].quantity+"</td>"+
                        "</tr>";
                txt += '<td><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeProduct(' + dataid + ')"/></td>';
                txt += '<td><input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="UnhideHidden3(' + dataid + ')"/></td>';
            }
            if(txt != ""){
                 $("#table11 tbody").detach();
                 $("#table11").append(txt).removeClass("hidden4");
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.status + ' ' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Обратно возвращается список, в данном случае, данного вида:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Iphone5s","brand":"Apple","price":1,"quantity":2}]
```

В случае успеха, должна заполниться и появиться следующего вида таблица:

```
<table id="table11" class="hidden4">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>brand</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>quantity</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>

</tr>
</tbody>
```

**Собственно, сам вопрос:**
Почему, *при использовании обычной кнопки* вида:

```
<button type="button" onclick="getFinds()">getIphones</button>
```

*все работает* и таблица заполняется нужными значениями, а *если использовать форму* и вызывать функцию getFinds() с помощью onsubmit следующим образом:

```
<form id="findprod" method="get" onsubmit="return getFinds()">
<p><b>Enter name or brand here:</b><br>
    <input type="text" size="40" name="findByNameOrBrand">
</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Get results">
    <input type="reset" value="Clean"></p>
```

, то *запрос не отрабатывает*?

Это нужно для того, чтобы можно было подставить далее значение из инпута findByNameOrBrand в url вместо "iphone" и получать список согласно введенному значению, сейчас инпут в форме абсолютно не важен, и мне просто хотелось бы узнать, почему не отрабатывает запрос через onsubmit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы попробовал для начала `onsubmit="getFinds(); return false;"`
Ну или, как вариант,

```
<form action="#">
    <input type="text" ... />
    <input type="button" onclick="getFinds();"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Работает! спасибо!